# Accessing Azure Blob Storage image In ML Studio

Tags: azure, image, blobstorage, ml-studio

I have an image data in a folder inside of a Blob storage. What I am trying to do is accessing this data inside of the ML Studio. I can access the data with SAS link, but I want to access via by giving path to this. Is it possible to do this? I want to visualize the image in ML Studio and get the content of the data (pixel numbers).
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are accessing the data in Azure ML Studio Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?tabs=Python-SDK#supported-paths) and Snapshot to pass the path to the Azure Storage.

[image]

Visualize the image data in Azure Machine Learning Studio using the 'opencv' library.